# pyqt4 qpainter segfault on a text drawing

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I want to use qpainter drawing abilities in a console application; for this purpose I tried using QCoreApplication with fictive timer that fires job processing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, Qt
from signal import signal, SIGINT
from sys import argv, exit

def sigint_handler(*args):
    QtGui.QApplication.quit()

class Processor(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Processor, self).__init__()

    def execute(self):
        image = QtGui.QImage('/tmp/ramdisk/output.png')
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(image)
        painter.drawText(10, 10, 'Text')
        painter.end()
        image.save('/tmp/ramdisk/output.png')
        QtGui.QApplication.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler)
    app = QtCore.QCoreApplication(argv)
    job = Processor()
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, job.execute)
    exit(app.exec_())
```

While it's working fine with simple things like `drawRect()`, with `drawText()` it crashes with segmentation fault.

So, is pyqt4 actually unable to work with fonts in console applications?

Comment: @tmoreau, I suppose it depends on used versions of qt and pyqt. So, on your side there are some safety checks which prevented segfault, but one way or another the problem remains.

Comment: @tmoreau, are you sure that there really was image located at /tmp/ramdisk/output.png? It is very likely cause of messages about bad engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before using `QtGui` classes and/or functions, you *must* create a `QApplication` (not a `QCoreApplication`). For a console application, just set the [GUIenabled](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#QApplication-2) argument to `False`:

```
    app = QtGui.QApplication(argv, False)
```

On X11, this avoids initialising the window system, and does not connect to the X server.

Comment: In my program, I am already creating a `QApplication` and have been using various `QtGui` classes and their functions. But when I add `QPainter`, it causes a segfault anyway.